# How to implement Tesseract.Xamarin?

Tags: android, xamarin

I am now trying to implement Tesseract.Xamarin in my app, but without any success. the problem i am facing has something to do with async methods. Basically in the documentation says:

```
TesseractApi api = new TesseractApi (context, AssetsDeployment.OncePerVersion);
await api.Init ("eng");
await api.SetImage("image_path");
string text = api.Text;
```

my exact code for this is:

```
TesseractApi api = new TesseractApi(this, AssetsDeployment.OncePerVersion);
                await api.Init("eng");
                await api.SetImage(App._file.Path);
                string text = api.Text;
```

The error that I get is : The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'
P.S I can not modify this method type because it is an override method (OnActivityResult)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to add the async keyword to your method (this does not change the method signature)

```
protected override async void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
{
    TesseractApi api = new TesseractApi(this, AssetsDeployment.OncePerVersion);
    await api.Init("eng");
    await api.SetImage(App._file.Path);
    string text = api.Text;
  }
}
```

Comment: api.Inti("eng") always returning false hence I didn't get any text :(. What I'm missing ?